# Valid Parenthesis Matching in MSO

Tags: logic, regular-language

What is the Monodic Second Order formula that encodes all binary strings that represent a valid parenthesis matching ? By this I mean 1s represent '(' and 0s represent ')' and at every position, number of 1s in the prefix is greater than or equal to the number of 0s .

Can someone tell me how to proceed ?

Thanks!

Comment: I also need to encode the fact that the string has equal number of 1s and 0s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. MSO captures exactly the regular languages.

Comment: Is it possible to capture it using MSO. I can't think of a DFA that captures the statement.

Comment: Try the other way around and prove that your language is not regular.